# about the subbundle in complex geometry by daniel huybrechts

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles

This question coming from page 68 of the book Compex Geometry by Daniel Huybrechts.
Here i write the question:
we have two holomorphic vector bundle $E,F$ given by the cocycles $\psi_{ij}$ and $\psi^{'}_{ij}$ respectively.
The exercise says that if for all $x \in U_i\cap U_j$ the matrix of $\{ \psi^{'}_{ij} \}$ has the form $\begin{bmatrix} \psi_{ij}&* \\ 0& \phi_{ij}  \end{bmatrix}$ than $E$ is a holomorphic sub-bundle of $F$, i.e. there exist a canonical injection $E \subset F$.
Conversely if $E$ is a sub-bundle of $F$ we can find cocycles of this form and the cokernel $F/E$ is described by the cocycles $\phi_{ij}$.
Can someone helping to show this fact? I can't figurt out why the matrix is not a diagonal matrix?

Comment: It follows more or less by direct construction, where are you stuck ? Maybe you can prove it first for $E,F$ line bundles in this case it's easier. The general proof is the same. In general, notice that if a cocycle are written in "block matrices" then the vector bundle will split, and one direct summand for each one block. So to answer your last question : if all the cocycle are a diagonal matrices it means that your vector bundle splits as sum of line bundles.